# Allow email client to send and receive data through modem-router firewall

Tags: email, routing

I'm working to allow my email client (Thunderbird) to send and receive data from remote servers, but when my modem-router firewall is turned on it doesn't work. As a result, I must setup a custom firewall configuration.

The account setup for Thunderbird is:

```
Incoming: IMAP
Server hostname: imap.googlemail.com
Port: 993
SSL: SSL/TLS
Authentication: OAuth2

Outgoing: SMTP
smtp.googlemail.com
Port: 465
SSL: SSL/TLS
Authentication: OAuth2
```

The custom firewall policy for the router is:

```
Port ID: IMAP
Enable: yes
Allowed protocol: TCP
Port range: 993:993
Protocol number: 0
Allow inbound: yes
Allow outbound: no

Port ID: SMTP
Enable: yes
Allowed protocol: TCP
Port range: 465:465
Protocol number: 0
Allow inbound: no
Allow outbound: yes
```

This configuration does not allow me to send and receive email. What else can I try?

Comment: Try to set Allow outbound instead of Allow inbound to Yes for IMAP. Although in your setup IMAP is for receiving mail, the firewall rule probably looks at the way you establish a connection (which is outbound to your e-mail server).

Comment: I set allow inbound and allow outbound to yes on both of them and it fixed it. Many thanks!

Comment: @pineappleman, looks like your right, should probably move to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set Allow outbound instead of Allow inbound to Yes for IMAP. Although in your setup IMAP is for receiving mail, the firewall rule probably looks at the way you establish a connection (which is outbound to your e-mail server).